# to be incurred or is to be incurred?

Tags: grammar, sentence-meaning

What is the difference between the following sentences ? Are they both grammatically correct ? if yes, what is the difference between the meanings ?

1- Your following payment shall cover also the additional cost **is to be incurred** due to the reasons stated in my previous letter.

2- Your following payment shall cover also the additional cost **to be incurred** due to the reasons stated in my previous letter.

More example sentences will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The first is grammatically incorrect.  At the very least it should be "additional cost which is to be incurred" or "additional cost which was incurred".  In that case the emphasis is on the fact that the additional costs have or will actually occur.  In the second sentence the emphasis is on explaining the reasons for the additional costs - whether those reasons actually arise and the additional costs are actually incurred is not addressed.  Personally, the most terse and elegant way of stating this in my opinion is just:

"Your following payment shall cover also the additional cost incurred due to the reasons stated in my previous letter"

Comment: Thank you very much for the clarification; however in your sentence, the cost has already been incurred. what if I want to refer the future costs ?